# Does "you are looking good" use "are looking" as a copulative verb?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I enjoyed the post titled: Different meaning of “looks good” vs. “looks well.”
Does the answer change when using a participle ("are looking," as opposed to "looks")? I think that "you are looking good" would be right according to the post, but I feel like I'm hitting on someone! But "you look good" doesn't strike me as flirtatious. Do participles or gerunds get the same copular/linking verb rules as the simple present?

Answer (score 1):

Normally stative predicates are supposed to be incompatible with the progressive form. E.g., *The car is red*, not **The car is being red.*

However, this is flouted in a special class of constructions generally referring to a person's behavior: *You're being annoying*, *You're being dumb*, etc., pointing out some temporary extreme of behavior. *You're looking good* falls into this pattern, as it suggests that the person appears, at the moment, more attractive than usual.

Yes, you are hitting on someone when you say that. Not a general rule about rules for linking verbs, just a special construction.

(Also, say "copula verb" rather than "copulative verb," lest people think you are hitting on them).

Comment: Haha! Thanks! So is "You're looking well" correct, even if "looking" is a copular verb? I feel like it's just one of Bryan Garner's 'skunked phrases' now, and I'll instead have to say something more specific: Your hair! Wow!

Comment: @JessicaPerry no that sounds awkward to say. "Look" isn't a copula verb, but it has stative aspectual class, similar to a copula verb.